# Re-applying matrix value got from different device changing position of the views Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, matrix

I have taken matrix values of different views from a particular device. If I apply the matrix again on the same device, the views are in the correct position. But when I apply the same matrix value to a different device, the position changes.
I know the device width, height, and density are different. I have tried multiplying matrix values with the density of the device. But still, the views placed are in the wrong position only.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

float[] scaledMatrix = new float[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  scaledMatrix[i] = matrix[i] * metrics.density;
}

// Apply the matrix value to the view.
myView.setMatrix(scaledMatrix);
```